# In Thunderbird, is it possible to block message formatting for some senders?

Tags: email, thunderbird, formatting

Some people use big ugly fonts with ugly colors in their mail. However, since these people are colleagues, I'd still like to read their mail, but without hurting my eyes :)

I'd also like to keep html formatting on by default. So is there something like "display this sender's emails as plain text"? I couldn't find it :-(

Comment: Do you want all emails to be displayed as plain text ?

Comment: @Sathya The question is looking to have only a certain set of senders have their emails to Peltier displayed as plain text while everyone else can go either way.

Comment: @Sathya : as I have clearly stated in my question, I *do not* want all emails to be displayed as plain text.

Comment: Do you have the option of using something like procmail?

Comment: @K Robinson: I'd *really* like to avoid using something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too have looked for a way to do this, but am unable too

Comment: If nobody knows the answer, I'll post it as a feature request on the Thunderbird bugzilla.

Comment: And dont forget to post back if they give you an answer

Comment: Here it is! https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=519656 I'm waiting for the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work, but go into the address book, right click a user > Properties then set this (and probably uncheck the HTML images box too):

[image]

Comment: I think that option is for what format the person in the address book wants to receive e-mails in, not the format you receive them in.